# How do i access an out parameter in a pl/sql proc via hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, plsql

I have a pl/sql procedure with the following signature

```
PROCEDURE pr_log_process_started (
p_process_id IN log_process_status.process_id%TYPE, 
p_run_id IN OUT log_process_status.run_id%TYPE);
```

How can i make a call to this proc via Hibernate and access the value of the second parameter after the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make a call to this proc via Hibernate and access the value of the second parameter after the call?

I don't think you can. At least, that's not my understanding of the [Chapter 16. Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures) of the official documentation:

> #### 16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying
>
> Hibernate3 provides support for
>   queries via stored procedures and
>   functions. Most of the following
>   documentation is equivalent for both.
>   The stored procedure/function must
>   return a resultset as the first
>   out-parameter to be able to work with
>   Hibernate. An example of such a stored
>   function in Oracle 9 and higher is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectAllEmployments
>     RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
> AS
>     st_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
> BEGIN
>     OPEN st_cursor FOR
>  SELECT EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYER,
>  STARTDATE, ENDDATE,
>  REGIONCODE, EID, VALUE, CURRENCY
>  FROM EMPLOYMENT;
>       RETURN  st_cursor;
>  END;
> ```
>
> To use this query in Hibernate you
>   need to map it via a named query.
>
> ```
> <sql-query name="selectAllEmployees_SP" callable="true">
>     <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
>         <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
>         <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
>         <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
>         <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
>         <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
>         <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
>         <return-property name="salary">
>             <return-column name="VALUE"/>
>             <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
>         </return-property>
>     </return>
>     { ? = call selectAllEmployments() }
> </sql-query>
> ```
>
> Stored procedures currently only
>   return scalars and entities.
>   `<return-join>` and
>   `<load-collection>` are not supported.
>
> #### 16.2.2.1. Rules/limitations for using stored procedures
>
> You cannot use stored procedures with
>   Hibernate unless you follow some
>   procedure/function rules. If they do
>   not follow those rules they are not
>   usable with Hibernate. If you still
>   want to use these procedures you have
>   to execute them via
>   `session.connection()`. The rules are
>   different for each database, since
>   database vendors have different stored
>   procedure semantics/syntax.
>
> Stored procedure queries cannot be
>   paged with
>   `setFirstResult()`/`setMaxResults()`.
>
> The recommended call form is standard
>   SQL92: `{ ? = call
>   functionName(<parameters>) }` or `{ ?
>   = call procedureName(<parameters>}`. Native call syntax is not supported.
>
> For Oracle the following rules apply:
>
> - A function must return a result set. The first parameter of a procedure
>     must be an OUT that returns a result
>     set. This is done by using a
>     SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10.
>     In Oracle you need to define a REF
>     CURSOR type. See Oracle literature for
>     further information.
>
> For Sybase or MS SQL server the
>   following rules apply:
>
> - The procedure must return a result set. Note that since these servers can
>     return multiple result sets and update
>     counts, Hibernate will iterate the
>     results and take the first result that
>     is a result set as its return value.
>     Everything else will be discarded.
> - If you can enable SET NOCOUNT ON in your procedure it will probably be
>     more efficient, but this is not a
>     requirement.

To sum up, either follow the rules or use raw JDBC via `session.connection()`.

Comment: Reckon that you are right on that one, in the end we provided a version of the proc as a function and call in a select from dual. Not the cleanest, but it works and keeps the config in the right place.